# Orchard CMS site url location in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, orchardcms, iis-8

I am trying to move my website to a different URL.  I don't have the admin password so I cant get into the Dashboard.  I need to change the URL from the database.  I know I need to reset the admin password.  I'm looking for a solution to that as well.

Answer (score 4):

Base url for site is stored in infoset inside table **Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord**, at very first row.

```
BaseUrl="http://localhost:10411"
```

---

Admin password is stored in the same table on the second row. Just change

```
PasswordFormat="Hashed" Password="AEZeLtFn4Z4sP...."
```

to

```
PasswordFormat="Clear" Password="YourTemporaryPassword"
```

Make sure you change your password once you log in so it's hashed again.

Answer (score 0):

Im running Version 1.7.2.

So far Ive found the passwords are in table **[Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord]**  And Yes, Just edit the :

```
PasswordFormat="Clear" Password="YourTemporaryPassword"
```

Like Xeevis said.  Then log in to reset your password.

As for the URL, its not Where Xeevis said, atleast for my version.  Ill update when I find it.